# Why is CPU used more than 100%?

Tags: linux

The 'top' shows that my CPU is used %1278. Is that possible? CentOs system.

top - 02:19:28 up 6 days, 13:05,  2 users,  load average: 40.12, 23.58, 14.90
    Tasks: 483 total,   2 running, 481 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    %Cpu(s): 35.0 us, 10.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 54.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
    KiB Mem : 15844449+total, 14859040+free, 56728560 used, 41812424 buff/cache
    KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16777212 free,        0 used. 15247632+avail Mem

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
365364 martin    20   0 63.177g 0.036t  37100 S  1278  2.4   9412:41 java                                                                                                                                    
117800 martin    20   0 72.577g 7.570g  37132 S 861.9  0.5  23:13.53 java                                                                                                                                    
153086 martin    20   0  148460   2948   1112 S  25.2  0.0   0:30.31 sshd                                                                                                                                    
114966 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   2.0  0.0   0:00.95 kworker/22:1                                                                                                                            
   308 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.7  0.0   0:02.62 kworker/37:1                                                                                                                            
   601 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   1.3  0.0   0:03.96 kworker/47:1                                                                                                                            
 92847 martin    20   0  160096   2660   1572 R   0.7  0.0   0:00.16 top                                                                                                                                     
171090 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:01.08 kworker/33:0                                                                                                                            
     8 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.36 migration/0                                                                                                                             
    10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   2:00.17 rcu_sched                                                                                                                               
    38 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.36 migration/6                                                                                                                             
   175 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.27 ksoftirqd/33
```

Comment: This isn't a good question for stack overflow, since it doesn't have anything to do with programming. You'll probably have better luck on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). That said, by default on a lot of distributions top shows CPU percentage as a percentage based on the number of cores you have (e.g. 16 cores is a maximum of 1600%). See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34436/309249).

Answer (score 2):

You have multicore CPU and program use multhithreading, so it use more then one CPU - more than 100% of one CPU, not all CPUs in system